# HTML CSS customize a box with border radius attribute

Tags: html, css

I want to customize this shape with CSS & HTML. It's the same trapezoid with some inverted border radius. How I can customize it? This is image like this.

[image]

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: See [this guide](https://itnext.io/how-to-make-a-fancy-inverted-border-radius-in-css-5db048a53f95)

Answer (score -1):

This will help you in the understanding trapezoid Shapes of CSS.

```css
#trapezoid {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 12vw;
  margin: 8vw 0;
}
#trapezoid:before,
#trapezoid:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
}
#trapezoid:before {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

[`The Shapes of CSS`](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

[`CSS transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)